# Chrome DevTools persisting changes via Styles panel

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, persistence

After i have set up workspaces and can now edit my SASS files directly via the **Sources** panel in Chrome DevTools, all changes i make in the styles panel persist throughout page reloads. Changes are made automatically to the generated CSS file but not the SASS file (the latter of which i read that its not possible – one must edit via the **Sources** tab).

Is this intended behaviour? How can i stop local changes in the styles panel (that are not saved to any of the files anyway) from persisting by being written into CSS files?

In the DevTools settings, **Enable Local Overrides** is turned **off**.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this same issue, but once I turned off Enable Local Overrides and cleared my cache/application data it worked as expected.